# How to globally set the preserveWhitespaces option in Angular to false?

Tags: angular

Since one of the beta releases of version 5, Angular has a new compiler option, `preserveWhitespaces`. The property is mentioned in [`CompilerOptions` type alias](https://angular.io/api/core/CompilerOptions) in the docs. The docs for the `Component` decorator describe [**its usage**](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preserveWhitespaces), and mention that the default in version 5 is `true` (no whitespace removal).

I've seen [the PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/18401/files), but from what I can tell from some tests is that the only way to use it is to supply `preserveWhitespace` to every `@Component` metadata. How can I set it to `false` globally, for *all* components, and then set it to `true` only for some components?

Comment: So you're saying if you set the `angularCompilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` it *doesn't* take effect? Could you show a [mcve] of the setup?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, so that's where it goes. Could you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović, do you use angular cli?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Yes.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović, then answer from jonsharpe will work

Comment: fellas... could somebody answer this with complete sentences and maybe even a link?? :)

Comment: Does anyone knows how to do the same with AngularDart (i.e. disable `preserveWhitespace` globally) ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This will be false by default starting with angular 6

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22027

For now, in JIT mode we can set it as part of [CompileOptions](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/core/src/linker/compiler.ts#L97-L110):

**main.ts**

```typescript
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, { preserveWhitespaces: false });
```

For aot we have to add this option to

**tsconfig.app.json**

```typescript
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  }
}
```

**[Angular-cli@1.4.5 example](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-cli-test)** where you can find the corresponding [commit](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-cli-test/commit/aeb2388a0cde2242bb41198912329c3a73150f35)

There is also [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7731) in angular-cli repo.

Comment: Did you mean the tsconfig.app.json, cause the one you typed is extending the tsconfig.json

Comment: Works fine, my large template drop by 50% time render

Comment: Here an aggressive behavior of preserveWhitespaces:false is discussed: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21049

Comment: Looking for a quick way to put a real space back in again? `{{ ' ' }}` is the safest, cleanest way I've found.

Comment: I use "ngPreserveWhitespace" as directive on elements I explicitly want to have whitespaces inside:

<div ngPreserveWhitespaces>
   <span class="badge badge-primary">1</span>
   <span class="badge badge-primary">2</span>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

In order to set angular compiler options in AOT compile (ng serve --aot, ng build --prod) you must alter the tsconfig.app.json to include:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "preserveWhitespaces": true
},
```

In order to set angular compiler options in JIT compile (ng serve) you must alter main.ts specifically the bootstrapModule call:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  preserveWhitespaces: true
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```