# Angular set preserveWhitespace in karma tests

Tags: angular

Following [How to globally set the preserveWhitespaces option in Angular to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018599/how-to-globally-set-the-preservewhitespaces-option-in-angular-to-false) I set my configuration to disable white space preservation globally but when I run my tests this is not honored.

How does one set this for tests. I tried manually configuring the `tsconfig.spec.json` but that had no positive effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the delay(seems I missed your comment on my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018599/how-to-globally-set-the-preservewhitespaces-option-in-angular-to-false))

Tests are runned with Jit compiler so setting options on tsconfig won't have any effect.

We can use [configureCompiler](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts#L97) method on `TestBed`. Since the signature of this method doesn't support `preserveWhitespases` option we have to cast options to `any`.

Here is how it could look like:

**app.component.spec.ts**

```typescript
beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureCompiler({ preserveWhitespaces: false } as any)
     .configureTestingModule({
       declarations: [
         AppComponent
       ],
     }).compileComponents();
}));
```