# Angular 4 : How to build for production without losing resposive design meta tags.

Tags: java, angular, typescript, ng-build

I've tested this with a new project, nothing unique.

`ng new debug-project`

Then I added some tags in the head section that resulted in this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DebugProject</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=0">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

After `ng build --prod`, the html is now looking like this, which can't be read by the browser. Notice the missing spaces in viewport meta tags values. `width, initial-scale=1`, become `width,initial-scale=1`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DebugProject</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1;minimum-scale=1;maximum-scale=1;user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="styles.ac89bfdd6de82636b768.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bf95165a1d5098766b92.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.8df9530e9d55fa951861.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there something wrong with my setup? Something I need to install on the project maybe?

Comment: Does this pose a functional problem or is it just something you noticed?

Comment: production `build` performs minification on your code which removes excess whitespace, comments, and optional tokens.?  what does browser's console shows?

Comment: which server are you using to serve the generated bundles from `dist`?

Comment: @Phix, yes, it's a problem, as I said, a browser needs to read these tags to display pages properly, it can't read them while they like that.

Comment: @Vikas nothing in console.

Comment: @Vikas I used the htttp-server, live-server and a production server --> Google. And this is not a serving issue. The file is just corrupt that's where we're at.

Comment: So the issue is cropped up because of minification in production build? does `ng serve` works fine?

Comment: `ng serve`, `ng build`, they work file, but not `ng build --prod`

Comment: Where did you get that having no space could cause an issue?

Comment: @David Did you run the two html blocks on a mobile browser to see the difference? Maybe you should try that.

Comment: Yes and it works fine. Good luck

Comment: Looking at this again you have 4 viewport tags. You only need one with the values comma separated.

Comment: @Phix is right, you should only use a single `viewport` entry and not expect browser to mix everything. Try using a single viewport entry and see if it helps

Comment: If you want it for SEO purpose then i would recommend you doing server-side rendering. https://angular.io/guide/universal

Answer (score 7):

From the angular/cli documentation, it looks like the production build flag minifies all of the html files by default, including index.html https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1861.  You can retain the formatting in the meta tags by wrapping them in an ignore tag as shown below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DebugProject</title>
  <base href="/">

  <!-- htmlmin:ignore -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=0">
  <!-- htmlmin:ignore -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, this seems worth a try, will check it out and report.

Answer (score 2):

I would try following this thread: [How to globally set the preserveWhitespaces option in Angular to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018599/how-to-globally-set-the-preservewhitespaces-option-in-angular-to-false?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The issue, form what i can tell, is that building in aot removes whitespace by default. Not building in aot is not a good idea, in my honest opinion. It saves a lot of work on the client and speeds your SPA up.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this command:

```
ng build -prod --no-aot
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: NO, that's a terrible idea.