# Is Angular 6 is removing default element margins?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, angular6

The issue I'm experiencing is that html elements (buttons in the examples below) in Angular 6 seem to be missing their default margin:

[Angular 5.2.2 example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umayz1) - has default margin/spacing between the buttons

[Angular 6.0 example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khuw6e) - is missing the margin/spacing between the buttons

I'm hoping someone can confirm this is an issue with angular - or point me to the root of the problem- before I open a github issue

Comment: Angular is **not** a CSS framework

Comment: Could be the removal of non-semantic whitespace from templates, that altered some layouts when I upgraded: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23764

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not changing the margins. The spaces in the angular 6.0 example are **stripped**, which would remove the margins between **inline-block** elements. 
There's a `preserveWhitespaces` configuration for angular, which is now (in 6.0 version) disabled by default.

Check this answer for more information: [How to globally set the preserveWhitespaces option in Angular to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018599/how-to-globally-set-the-preservewhitespaces-option-in-angular-to-false)

Answer (score 5):

You can try adding `preserveWhiteSpace` as the space between your buttons is not margin but a whitespace.

```
@Component({ 
   selector: 'app-employee-list', 
   templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html', 
   styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css'], 
   preserveWhitespaces: true 
}) 
export class EmployeeListComponent { 
}
```

To do it across the application, you can do:

```
[…] 
"angularCompilerOptions": { 
  "preserveWhitespaces": true 
} 
[…]
```