# Angular 6 and Bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I developed ASP.NET MVC 5 single page application using Angular 5 and Bootstrap. Recently I updated app to use Angular 6. Now HTML layout does not have spaces between Bootstrap controls.

For example this HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
 </form>
```

Firefox dev tools edit HTML option displays as:

```
<form class="form-inline"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com"></div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button></form>.
```

When I edit the HTML and add whitespace or line break like in the first example, then browser displays spaces between controls as has to be.

Is Angular 6 compacts HTML of component templates? How do I make the app (that uses Bootstrap) look as expected?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46018599/1009922).

Answer (score 0):

You can get excellent design components from https://material.angular.io/.
See https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started