# Angular 7 post-upgrade styling issue

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, npm

We've upgraded our application from *Angular 5.2 to 7.2* and the styling got messed up. The spacing between some elements (for example: icons and text) has changed, disappeared or decreased.

Have any of you encountered an issue like this after upgrading an Angular application or the following packages?

I already reverted back every possible package to their staging versions, but it didn't solve the problem.

I have no idea where to start the troubleshooting to find the source of the problem. **The styling and the HTML haven't been changed.**

We updated:

- Bootstrap: from 4.1.0 to 4.3.1
- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap: from 1.1.2 to 4.0.0
- ngx-bootstrap: from 2.0.5 to 4.0.0

The styling is global from the *angular.json*:
[image]

Where we import the used Bootstrap components:
[image]

The *package.json* look like this:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.11",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.12",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.6.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "7.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
    "acorn": "6.1.1",
    "angular2-image-zoom": "1.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "braintree-web-drop-in": "1.16.0",
    "core-js": "2.6.5",
    "file-saver": "2.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "htmllint": "0.7.3",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.9.3",
    "ng-recaptcha": "4.2.1",
    "ng2-order-pipe": "0.1.5",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "7.4.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "4.1.2",
    "ngx-webstorage": "3.0.2",
    "popper.js": "1.14.7",
    "print-js": "1.0.54",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.4.0",
    "tslib": "1.9.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.7",
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.11",
    "@types/file-saver": "2.0.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "11.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "4.11.0",
    "protractor": "6.0.0",
    "sort-json": "2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.0.3",
    "tslint": "5.14.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. How are you doing the styling? Globally? In the Component decorator with `styles:[]` or through `styleUrls:[]`, etc

Comment: Have you tried to clear browser cache? and when upgrading and open inspect element, Did you notice any changes?

Comment: Are you using ng-deep in your styles? https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep - I didn't think this was removed in 7 but thought I'd flag this

Comment: Did you also upgrade bootstrap?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe from Angular 6 the `preserveWhitespace` option is false by default. To turn it on again globally you can add an option in `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "preserveWhitespaces": true
}
```

Or you can use the directive `ngPreserveWhitspaces` on any elements where you need the whitespace to be preserved.

See [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preserving-whitespace) for some (quite hidden) documentation on it.

Comment: You led me to the answer, which was this one, but I accept it and left this comment, because your answer is still good for another cases:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018599/how-to-globally-set-the-preservewhitespaces-option-in-angular-to-false