# Why Angular removes spaces between inline tags?

Tags: angular, spaces

I was surprised what Angular removes spaces between inline HTML tags following each other.

```
<p><span>1</span> <span>2</span> <span>3</span></p>
```

This code will be rendered as `"123"` instead of `"1 2 3"`.

Is this behavior correct?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-remove-spaces

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As mentioned in the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preserving-whitespace), the compiler option `preserveWhitespaces` is `false` by default. With that setting, the Angular compiler removes the spaces between your `span` elements. To preserve the spaces without changing the compiler option, you can use the Angular entity `&ngsp;` which is replaced by a space in the rendered HTML:

```
<p><span>1</span>&ngsp;<span>2</span>&ngsp;<span>3</span></p>
```

An alternative method is to set the `ngPreserveWhitespaces` attribute:

```
<p ngPreserveWhitespaces><span>1</span> <span>2</span> <span>3</span></p>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1lgjs?file=src/app/app.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: I didn't know about attribute `ngPreserveWhitespaces`. It is working, thanks.
As for the HTML entity `&ngsp;`, may be do you mean `&nbsp;`?

Comment: I really mean `&ngsp;`, as indicated in the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preserving-whitespace) and as shown in [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1lgjs?file=src/app/app.component.html). That entity is defined by Angular and recognized by the compiler. It is rendered as a normal space, as opposed to `&nbsp;` which is the HTML unbreakable space.

Comment: I looked for symbol `ngsp` and did not find it in Unicode. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why anyone would suggest fixing this via CSS. Angular is too aggressive with its whitespace removal and needs better context awareness.

Using `<strong>` in the middle of a `<p>` block works exactly as expected with no whitespace removal. *However*, if it happens to be next to another inline tag within the same paragraph, such as a `<span>` or `<em>`, then the space between the two will be removed, even if there is unwrapped text on either side of the inline elements.

To enable whitespace preservation for the project, assuming you're using the CLI, you'll need to update two files in your project (check the src directory).

**tsconfig.app.json**

Add this to the end of the document, before the last curly brace:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": true
  }
```

**main.ts**

Change:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

To:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  preserveWhitespaces: true
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The first file will preserve whitespace during development (`ng serve`) and the second will do the same for productions builds (`ng build --prod`)

Comment: Angular forces you to pick your poison.  That fact that an optimization like `"preserveWhitespaces": true` breaks inline spacing is really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

By Angular 6 for better performance Angular team turned off `preserveWhitespaces` as false.
So If you need to turn that on you need to do it manually, you can do it globally or per component.

> True to preserve or false to remove potentially superfluous whitespace
>   characters from the compiled template. Whitespace characters are those
>   matching the \s character class in JavaScript regular expressions.
>   Default is false, unless overridden in compiler options.

See next 2 links for extra details:
https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preservewhitespaces

[How to globally set the preserveWhitespaces option in Angular to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018599/how-to-globally-set-the-preservewhitespaces-option-in-angular-to-false)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct because your white spaces are outside of the html elements and will not get rendered. Try putting them inside the spans:

`<p><span>1 </span><span>2 </span><span>3 </span></p>`

Comment: Try it with vanilla HTML though, it doesn't remove the spaces then.

Comment: Yeah, but that is Angular for you @JohnMontgomery

Comment: _"white spaces are outside of the html elements and will not get rendered"_ is true for **block** elements but not **inline** elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally best practice to leave all styling related functionality to CSS.
If you want some spacing between the numbers try using `padding` or `margin` and `display: inline-block` or `display: flex`.

HTMLs job is only to contain markup, and as your issue reveals, it is not always 100% clear what is going to happen to the HTML. For example maybe in the future your code might be modified by something similiar to `preserveWhitespaces` but instead of affecting the whitespace outside of a tag it might minimize the whitespace inside the tag as well.

This is just a theoretical situation but its important to consider.

Again I highly reccomend solving the task of spacing your numbers by using CSS.